# issue with understanding json syntax

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, arrays, array-difference

I have a json file

**NAME:abcd.json**

Its content starts like following(this looked pretty wierd to me as this was the first time i came across such json file)-->

```
["51b59c2081ecf", [["parties", 0.0793, 0.238], ["signature", 0.002, 0.006]]]
["51b59c2683e7d", [["parties", 0.0037, 0.011]]]
["51b59c255e1fb", [["parties", 0.0037, 0.011]]]
["51b59c2e95da5", [["parties", 0.0037, 0.011]]]
```

I came across another json file

**NAME:color.json**

```
{
    "colorsArray":[{
            "colorName":"red",
            "hexValue":"#f00"
        },
        {
            "colorName":"green",
            "hexValue":"#0f0"
        },
        {
            "colorName":"blue",
            "hexValue":"#00f"
        },
        {
            "colorName":"black",
            "hexValue":"#000"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using D3js and I want to push the content of abcd.json in to an array so that I can use that data further.

**MyQuestions:**

1. if both of them are json.files than why there exist some difference between their syntax.My entire d3 code depends on this data.

2.How do I push the json data to a variable say Var data.

currently I am providing var data some static value for some temporary testing,Like this->

```
 var data= [
        ["51b59c2a019af", [["signature", 0.002, 0.006], ["parties", 0.0037, 0.011]]],
        ["51b59c2635997", [["fashion", 0.002, 0.006], ["parties", 0.0037, 0.011],["royal-challenge", 0.002, 0.6]]],
        ["51b59c29c39bf", [["parties", 0.0037, 0.1], ["signature", 0.002, 0.006]]]
           ];
```

Comment: The former does not validate as JSON, the latter does. The former consists of 4 separate arrays, each _individually_ being valid JSON.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson:but I have a json file which has same syntax.So basically there is no point in giving that file a .json extension coz it is not json???

Comment: The suffix `.json` would seem a bit strange, even if each line individually seems to parse as valid JSON, the whole file as a unit does not.

Comment: So how do i load the entire data from abcd.json to a var data??my entire project depends on that.I have completed it and now just need to do this last thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the former one is not a proper JSON, but most of the library and JSON.parse in browser will still parse it and return an array.

See below jQuery code:

```
parseJSON: function( data ) {
    // Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
    if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {
        return window.JSON.parse( data );
    }

    if ( data === null ) {
        return data;
    }

    if ( typeof data === "string" ) {

        // Make sure leading/trailing whitespace is removed (IE can't handle it)
        data = jQuery.trim( data );

        if ( data ) {
            // Make sure the incoming data is actual JSON
            // Logic borrowed from http://json.org/json2.js
            if ( rvalidchars.test( data.replace( rvalidescape, "@" )
                .replace( rvalidtokens, "]" )
                .replace( rvalidbraces, "")) ) {

                return ( new Function( "return " + data ) )();
            }
        }
    }

    jQuery.error( "Invalid JSON: " + data );
}
```

It uses `new Function()` to create the object, which is similar to `eval()` (but much better because it cannot access the scope of your codes), so it will still parse it in this case.

Comment: What is the above code doing,i mean there is no filoe name include in it ..........and
so how do i load my json data in to my var data???

Comment: So now you have `var data` to hold those array?

Comment: Exactly!!!!just for temporary purpose...i want to load json data in to that var data not?am i clear?

Comment: I think the only way is writing code to map those data back in a proper JSON format like `{ 'name' : 'value' }` or `{ 'name' : ['value1', 'value2'] }`, etc. But you need to do it by yourself, since no one except you know what's you data mean, what's the keys, and what's the values.

Comment: If you get those arrays in string: `var dataStr = '[["51b59c2a019af", [["signature", 0.002, 0.006], ["parties", 0.0037, 0.011]]], ["51b59c2635997", [["fashion", 0.002, 0.006], ["parties", 0.0037, 0.011],["royal-challenge", 0.002, 0.6]]],["51b59c29c39bf", [["parties", 0.0037, 0.1], ["signature", 0.002, 0.006]]]]'`, just use `var data = JSON.parse(dataStr)`

Comment: I will get proper json format after doing this...are you sure??

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file contents in a string, you can easily convert it to valid JSON by wrapping it inside `[]` and adding the appropriate commas;

```js
var str = '["51b59c2081ecf", [["parties", 0.0793, 0.238], ["signature", 0.002, 0.006]]]' + "\n" + 
          '["51b59c2683e7d", [["parties", 0.0037, 0.011]]]' + "\n" +
          '["51b59c255e1fb", [["parties", 0.0037, 0.011]]]' + "\n" +
          '["51b59c2e95da5", [["parties", 0.0037, 0.011]]]' + "\n";

var valid_json = '[' + str.split(/[\n\r]/).
                           filter(function(val) { return (val !== ''); }).
                           join(',') + ']';

console.log(valid_json);
```

Comment: the thing is i have around 1lakh records,i have posted only 4-5 of them for simplicity sake...are you sure this is the only method!!!

Comment: @MESSIAH If there's more info on how you're fetching the file, there may be more ways.

Comment: the thing is i got this humongous json file from my senior who said that he have used some python and php to bring that data in to that wierd json format!!!how to go about it now..I tried out my entire project,its working fine but temporarily i have used static data...now when i thought i am almost at the finish line...this json thing is freaking me out,how to go about it now.??my project---->

http://jsfiddle.net/ddfsb/2/

Comment: @MESSIAH How are you planning to fetch the file? All in one go as an AJAX call?

Comment: no no no.....i dont need any ajax in here...
I just want a ready-made xyz.json file having data in json format.There is a conventional way of loading json data in variable the d3way,but since my json is so wierd that conventional method is not accepting the data.Am i clear??

Comment: You should definitely try `d3.json` since some JSON parsers are relaxed and it _may_ work, but if that will not work I can't see any straight forward option besides fetching the file into a string and parsing that. If that's really not an option, you should be able to take a look at the [d3.tsv](https://github.com/vlandham/d3.tsv) extension and see if you can do an extension for your file type, but that is not something I've tried so that I can guide you.

Comment: let me try,i will let you know !!!
What do you think,should i get my hands dirty with some php and pyhton  to get the data in desired format or I should manipulate the current abcd.json

Comment: @MESSIAH Definitely, if it's an option to convert it server side, do it there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32558/discussion-between-messiah-and-joachim-isaksson)

Comment: yaa,there is no other way..i have to go back and redo my php stuff so that i get the json data properly!!!but When i do it obviously i will have to do some parsing...after i do my parsing can i know how my var data would look like??and do i need to change my d3 code for that...am i clear with my question?

Comment: @MESSIAH If you just add a leading `[`, a trailing `]` and a comma between each line, the regular `d3.json` parser will be able to parse it to an array without problems. That should be very easy to do using any server side scripting language.

Comment: I am going through some w3schools tutorial now for getting more insights on json...but i dint completely understood what you explained??i think we should move to chat...

Comment: how do i put the content of my content.json in to variable var data ...In my code http://jsfiddle.net/ddfsb/2/
Any idea...I am stuck